# Calling and using the .interrupt() method?

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt, interrupt-handling

How exactly do i call the `.interrupt()` method? When I have `Thread.sleep(1000)`, when and where do I call the `.interrupt()` method? is it after? What I want to do is stop `Thread.sleep(1000)` midway.

EDIT::

i'm having trouble stopping a thread in the middle. This is part of my code, in the `StoplightThread` class I have problems on the first if statement. What it is supposed to do is wait at least 10 secs then allow the user to press the button so they can change the light, if the button is pressed it should stop the running thread in this case `Thread.sleep(40000)`. What happens is when I press the button it changes the light but does not stop the thread. If I press the button while there is still 20secs left it will add 20secs to the 10secs for the yellow light, making it yellow for 30 secs.

Edit: if you are wondering, `stoplightCanvas.x == 3` is green, `stoplightCanvas.x == 2` is yellow, and `stoplightCanvas.x == 1` is red.

```
class StoplightCanvas extends Canvas implements ActionListener
{  

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getSource() == cross) {
            isPressed = true;
            if (x == 3 && canCross)
                x = 2;     
        }
        repaint();
    }

}


class StoplightThread extends Thread
{
    StoplightCanvas stoplightCanvas;

    StoplightThread(StoplightCanvas stoplightCanvas) {
        this.stoplightCanvas = stoplightCanvas;
    }

    public void run() 
    {
        if (stoplightCanvas.x == 3){
               Thread.sleep(10000);
               stoplightCanvas.canCross = true;
               Thread.sleep(40000);
               if(stoplightCanvas.isPressed)
                   StoplightThread.interrupt();
           } else if (stoplightCanvas.x == 2) {
               Thread.sleep(10000);    
           } else if (stoplightCanvas.x == 1) {
               Thread.sleep(60000);
           }
       } catch (InterruptedException e){}

           stoplightCanvas.toggleColor();
           stoplightCanvas.repaint();
        }           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were going to call `interrupt()` at all, you'd call it from a different thread than the sleep().

If you want to interrupt the sleep() midway from the *same* thread, you can do this:

```
   Thread.sleep( 500 );
   ... 
   Thread.sleep( 500 );
```

All that said, sleep() can be a code smell.

**EDIT (after OP edit):**

Call *interrupt()* on the StoplightThread from the GUI thread in your actionPerformed() method.

Comment: well not exactly midway. So i have to make a new thread just to stop it?

Comment: Do you want it stopped after a period of time, or when an event occurs?

Comment: A single thread can't do two things concurrently. If you decided to make it sleep, it sleeps. Until the timeout has elapsed. If you don't want to sleep so ;ong, just reduce the timeout.

Comment: Presumably you want to stop it because something happened - the user clicked a button or an asynchronous call returned, or...  Whatever that something is, it should be coming from a different thread, if you set things up properly.  In that thread, you'd interrupt your sleeping thread.  Maybe you could provide more details on what you're doing.

Comment: @FJam: if an event is received and handled, it is by another thread. A thread can't both sleep and handle an event. So interrupt the sleeping thread from the event handling thread.

Comment: Okay, then you need something to detect when the event has occurred. It can't be the thread that's sleep()ing, because it's asleep. So it either has to be a different thread or you have to block in the same thread until the event occurs.

Comment: so in the code i have right now, I have to make another thread class?

Comment: Not if you can use the Thread that started StoplightThread, which is likely the GUI thread.

Answer (score 1):

try this example

```
public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        t.interrupt();
    }
}
```

it prints

```
java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at test.Test1$1.run(Test1.java:9)
```

Comment: wait im confused... why would `Thread.sleep(2000);` start? it was t.start() was called afterwards.

Comment: t.start() is called lower in the file the the anonymous class definition, whose run() method is called as a result of t.start(), which leads to Thread.sleep(2000) being called.

Comment: when we create a new Thread it's just an object it doesnt work yet. when we call t.start() JVM invokkes its method run() in a parallel thread

Answer (score 0):

You need a reference to the thread you want to interrupt, so that you can call `interrupt()` on it from a different thread.